# s3-dist-cp groupBy equivalent on Dataproc using hadoop distcp commands

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc, distcp, s3distcp

On an EMR, I am using `s3-dist-cp --groupBy` in order to name the file with random `fileName` in a folder to a name that i wish to rename it to in S3:

```sh
s3-dist-cp --groupBy='.*(folder_in_hdfs).*' --src=hdfs:///user/testUser/tmp-location/folder_in_hdfs --dest=s3://testLocation/folder_in_s3
```

Example:

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs:///user/testUser/tmp-location/folder_in_hdfs
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop hadoop          0 2019-04-05 14:54 hdfs:///user/testUser/tmp-location/folder_in_hdfs/file.csv/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop hadoop     493077 2019-04-05 14:54 hdfs:///user/testUser/tmp-location/folder_in_hdfs/file.csv/part-00000-12db8851-31be-4b08-8a93-1887e534941d-c000.csv
```

After running s3-dist-cp,

```
aws s3 ls s3://testLocation/folder_in_s3/
s3://testLocation/folder_in_s3/file.csv
```

However, I would like to achieve this functionality on Dataproc using `hadoop distcp` commands and write the file to a GCS location `gs://testLocation/folder_in_gs/file.csv`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Dataproc doesn't have such capability in DistCp.

That said, it's trivial to achieve the same result with simple bash script that uses [gsutil compose](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose), after running DistCp:

```sh
DESTINATION=gs://bucket/path/to/destination/file
FILES=($(gsutil ls gs://testLocation/**folder_in_gs**))
gsutil compose "${FILES[@]::32}" "${DESTINATION}"
echo "${FILES[@]:32}"| xargs -n 1 | xargs -i gsutil compose "${DESTINATION}" {} "${DESTINATION}"
gsutil -m rm gs://testLocation/**folder_in_gs**
```